# How to send gzipped json response from Google Cloud Functions?

Tags: json, node.js, google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-functions, serverless

My JSON responses in one of my Google Cloud Functions could be reduced up to 70-80% in size if I respond using gzip compression.

How can I send a compressed json response from my Functions (trigger via http(s))?

This would also mean I would save on a lot of network expenses with google cloud platform, and a faster loading of the data for mobile consumers of the data.

I've tried using the `zlib` native module but no luck...

```
if (req.get('Accept-Encoding') && req.get('Accept-Encoding').indexOf('gzip') > -1) {

    interpretation.gzip = true;

    const zlib = require('zlib');

    res.set('Content-Type', 'text/plain');
    res.set('Content-Encoding', 'gzip');

    zlib.gzip(JSON.stringify(interpretation), function (error, result) {
        if (error) throw error;
        res.status(200).send(result);
    })

} else {
    interpretation.gzip = false;
    res.status(200).send(interpretation);
}
```

In Postman, the size of the response is the same, the content-type has changed, but there is no `Content-Encoding` header set in the response...

[image: At the top (white background) is the my request's headers. Works well, and the header is received by my application. The response headers miss my Content-Encoding.]

Comment: Take at the [App Engine FAQ](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/kb/), the answer to the question "_How do I serve compressed content?_". Also, in this [group post](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!msg/firebase-talk/770_rjbVfmg/4E6HH8RxAwAJ) there's an example: `curl -v "https://us-central1-<project>.cloudfunctions.net/test" -H "User-Agent: Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Linux x86_64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/59.0.3071.115 Safari/537.36" -H "Accept-Encoding: gzip"`

Comment: How did you solve this? Do you know if a need to make my function into an express app to control compression? Or can I set it using the function's `response` object only?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Look at the [App Engine FAQ](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/kb/), specifically the answer to the question "**How do I serve compressed content?**":

> ....To force gzipped content to be served, clients may supply 'gzip' as the value of both the **Accept-Encoding** and 
>   **User-Agent** request headers. Content will never be gzipped if no **Accept-Encoding** header is present...

Also, in [this group post](https://groups.google.com/d/msg/firebase-talk/770_rjbVfmg/4E6HH8RxAwAJ) there's an example of how to send a request with Cloud Functions using the combination of `Accept-Encoding`, `User-Agent`:

```
curl -v "https://us-central1-<project>.cloudfunctions.net/test" -H "User-Agent: Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Linux x86_64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/59.0.3071.115 Safari/537.36" -H "Accept-Encoding: gzip"
```

Answer (score 0):

You can probably try to use [zlib](https://nodejs.org/api/zlib.html) module to handle compression and set an appropriate encoding to the response:

```
exports.helloWorld = function helloWorld(req, res) {
  const zlib = require('zlib');

  // Obtain JSON stream from your source...

  res.status(200);

  res.set('Content-Type', 'text/plain');
  res.set('Content-Encoding', 'gzip');

  json.pipe(zlib.createGzip()).pipe(res);
};
```

Of course, it's required to first check whether client accepts `gzip`. Also, using `zlib` encoding can be expensive, and the results ought to be cached.

Comment: just updated the question.. have tried with Zlib but no luck... seems like the `res.set('Content-Encoding', 'gzip');` is not going through...

Comment: @Lazhar: interesting issue. Let me check it out in my sandbox then : )

Answer (score -1):

Expressjs [Production best practices: performance and reliability](https://expressjs.com/en/advanced/best-practice-performance.html#dont-use-synchronous-functions) says below, which could be adapted for basic Node.js.  They use the popular [compression package available on NPM](https://www.npmjs.com/package/compression).

#### Use gzip compression

Gzip compressing can greatly decrease the size of the response body and hence increase the speed of a web app. Use the compression middleware for gzip compression in your Express app. For example:

```
var compression = require('compression')
var express = require('express')
var app = express()
app.use(compression())
```