# How to enable gzip compression from firebase storage?

Tags: firebase, firebase-storage

I would like to enable gzip compression on csv files that I have stored on firebase storage.
The aim is to be able to download them faster from a javascript web app in ajax.

I have a download link like this : `https://firebasestorage.googleapis.com/v0/b/xxxx.appspot.com/o/xxxxxxxx.csv?alt=media&token=xxxxxx-xxxx-xxxx-xxxx-xxxxxxx`

That I'm able to load and parse correctly in JavaScript:

```
Papa.parse('https://firebasestorage.googleapis.com/v0/b/xxxx.appspot.com/o/xxxxxxxx.csv?alt=media&token=xxxxxx-xxxx-xxxx-xxxx-xxxxxxx', {
  download: true,
  header: true,
  worker: true, 
  dynamicTyping: true,
  complete: function(results) {
      // (...)
  }
});
```

But it's not gzipped.
I'm not sure how this should be done.

Can this be done via the gsutil tool?
Any other ways to achieve this?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to send gzipped json response from Google Cloud Functions?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48309760/how-to-send-gzipped-json-response-from-google-cloud-functions)

Comment: ^ that's not an exact duplicate, but nevertheless explains how to do it.

Comment: @MartinZeitler That question doesn't cover firebase-storage I'm afraid. Or at least I don't understand the accepted answer :s  where do I change things?

Comment: there is no other option - hence one cannot run code on a storage service. you'd have to serve the gzipped `csv` response with a HTTP triggered Cloud Function, which fetches from Firebase Storage.

Comment: @MartinZeitler Thanks! Let me know if I understand this right : I would have to buy a https://cloud.google.com/products/ instance, make it read the firebase csv, compress it and serve the gzipped version? (That's too complex for me so I'm probably going to abandon here)

Comment: nope. https://firebase.google.com/docs/functions is what I mean; in particular https://firebase.google.com/docs/functions/http-events ...while you'll find no single storage service, which may run code, simply because this is not the duty of a storage service.